# How can I save the previous text in textarea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am using a button to input text from a text input and displaying it in a text area using following code.

```
public function sendMessage():void
{
    mytextarea.text = textinput.text;
    textinput.text = "";
}
```

The problem I am facing is , whenever I add new line or others it replaces the previous text, I want the previous text in text area to stay there.

Any hints how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the text, append new text with the previous texts.

```
mytextarea.text += textinput.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @taskinoor 's answer, you should try use [`appendText()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#appendText%28%29) where possible over the `+=` operator.

From documentation for `flash.text.TextField`:

> Appends the string specified by the newText parameter to the end of
>   the text of the text field. This method is more efficient than an
>   addition assignment (`+=`) on a text property (such as
>   `someTextField.text += moreText`), particularly for a text field that
>   contains a significant amount of content.
>
> Parameters
>
> `newText:String` — The string to append to the existing text.

So your code would be:

```
mytextarea.appendText(textinput.text);
```